# PDOException::("could not find driver") Laravel & sql server

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, wampserver

I'm trying to connect Laravel with a multiple sqlserver databases, I defined the connections on my database.php file correctly :

```
'connections' => [



    'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '16000'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'dbname'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'me'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'me'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
    ],
    'sqlsrv2' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '16000'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_2', 'dbname2'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'me'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'me'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
    ],

],
```

and set my .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=16000
DB_DATABASE=dbname
DB_USERNAME=me
DB_PASSWORD=me
```

I try to verify the connectivity to my sql server database from another application and it's working perfectly. then I created a model on my laravel application and once I type php artisan migrate I get this error :
[image]

anyone can help to resolve this problem ?

UPDATE !

After adding pdo sqlsrv extensions to my ext folder and my php.ini i get this error :
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

UPDATE 3 :

After installing odbc 13 i got this problem
[image]

Comment: try `php artisan cache:clear`, `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: I still get the error :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, WAMPServer has 2 seperate `php.ini` files.

One is used by PHP under Apache and the other by the PHP CLI.

I see you are using the CLI, so you need to check that you have included the SQL Server drivers extension in the CLI `php.ini` file.

You will find that in:

```
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php{version}\php.ini
```

You have to edit this manually, there is no menu link to do this, the menu link to edit the `php.ini` only edits the PHP under Apache version of `php.ini`

> Make sure you edit the `php.ini` file in the folder that matches the version of PHP you are actually using for this project, as of course you can have multiple versions of PHP installed under WAMPServer

UPDATE: Second Problem

You have added the 32bit AND 64 bit SQL Server drivers to your ext folder!

Your WAMPServer menu shows

```
1. php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64 
2. php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x32
3. php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64 
4. php__pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x32
```

> as you are using 64 bit wamp, you should only have these 2

```
1. php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64 
2. php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64
```

Comment: I've just added the extensions to ext folder of my php and i edited my php.ini but i get an error saying: no 'extension' = and it show the extensions that i've just added

Comment: Show that error in your question, after a line with `UPDATE` in it

Comment: I added only the 64 bit version still get the problem

Comment: I've updated the question with the problem i've got after adding the extension in phpforapache.ini too

Comment: To access SQL Server from PHP you need those ODBC Drivers.

Comment: Did you install from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Comment: And here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50420

Comment: I've updated the question with the problem after installing odbc 13

Comment: Did you check password?

Comment: Yes password checked

Comment: Probleme resolved ! the problem was really in my sql server authentification !

Comment: Phew, thats a relief. I was running out of ideas :)